# Imaging and deployment

Tags: license, disk-image

so as i understand an image is a snapshot of the hard disk which can be installed in another computer. It contains the data, software which can be deployed in the next computer.

So if i made an image of this computer which has the OS windows 7 and microsoft office in it and install it in the next computer. So now that computer will also have OS windows 7 and Microsoft office right?

Then how about licensing? Will the new computer gets free windows and microsoft office?

Pls clarify. Thanks

Comment: They will either require re-activation (which may fail) or will still be activated, but against the license. Free doesn't mean genuine.

Comment: "Then how about licensing?" - This entirely depends on your current license.  If you have a VLK you simply connect the new machine to the same domain that has the KMS, and provided you have the licenses, your machine would activate.  I am guessing we are not talking a configuration like that, but what you have is not clear, so edit your question (if you don't mind) and clarify what you do have.  Be as specific as possible, the details in a case like this, change possible answers to irrelevant answers quickly

Answer (score 1):

> So now that computer will also have OS windows 7 and Microsoft office right?

Right. But hardware differences might cause the new computer not to boot
if drivers are missing.

> Then how about licensing? Will the new computer gets free windows and microsoft office?

No : You will need to re-activate Windows and Office.